# C++ dynamic (multi-stage) 3D vector instantiation and element assignment

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, variable-assignment, dynamic-memory-allocation

Okay, so I need to create a 3D data-structure at run-time, I decided to use std::vector, the problem is as follows: I know the dimension of the 1st dimension at instantiation time (when I create the object I'm using it in), but I don't know the dimension of the second until run-time, and the size of 3rd dimensions can vary. **I have created the 3D vector** and the run-time doesn't complain, however I'm having difficulty **assigning values** to the elements.

This code is part of an object I'm creating. In the class definition I have:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<double> > > splits;
```

Then in the object constructor, in order to create/allocate the first dimension, I have:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfDimOne; i++){ //create 1st dimension
    splits.push_back( std::vector< std::vector<double> >() );
}
```

based on user input I need to create 2nd dimension of a certain size, I call a method for this:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfDimOne; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<sizeOfDimTwo; j++) //create second dimension
        splits[i].push_back( std::vector<double>() );
}
```

However, when I get to assigning values:

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfDimThree; i++){
   splits[dim1][dim2].push_back( someValue ); //adding an element to the 3rd dim
}
```

(The *someValue* changes constantly (and is a double), and you don't have to worry about lower dimension indexing, everything checks out.) The problem is - when I checked *splits[dim1][dim2][i]* the value was ***0.0*** for (presumably all) entries, naturally this is not what was provided by *someValue*.

I have also tried creating the 3rd dimension using *.resize(sizeOfDimThree)* and then assigning using

```
splits[dim1][dim2][i] = whatever;
```

but that didn't work at all - no object/element was created at all.

I realize this perhaps isn't the most straight forward manner of phrasing the question, but I believe it is the most accurate, as there might be multiple-points of failure.

Comment: YOu do realize you could use a 1 dim vector and do the math yourself...

Comment: Are you passing splits anywhere by value? (i.e. instead of by reference). Or all operations on it done by member methods of the class?

Comment: Have you considered using boost::multi_array, it has the resize etc.

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "no object/element was created at all.", how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @ Michael Dorgan: Yes.
@ C Johnson: all operations on it are performed by class methods.
@ Gearoid Murphy: I checked the size of each dimension in turn, during my debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out, that technically everything was correct (albeit inefficient, which I got around by using .resize() for appropriate dimensions in turn), my 'problem' was (as it tends to be) a very stupid mistake, to verify that everything was assigned I used:

```
printf("value assigned: %d", splits[dim1][dim2][dim3]);
```

instead of (since *splits* is a **double**):

```
printf("value assigned: %.3f", splits[dim1][dim2][dim3]);
```

Moral of the story: pay attention to how you treat the variable datatype & post **full source code.**

Answer (score 1):

See if boost::multi array could help, it can do things like:

```
 typedef boost::multi_array<int, 3> array_type;

  array_type::extent_gen extents;
  array_type A(extents[3][3][3]);
  A[0][0][0] = 4;
  A[2][2][2] = 5;
  A.resize(extents[2][3][4]);
  assert(A[0][0][0] == 4);
  // A[2][2][2] is no longer valid.
```

Here is the link : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_example

Comment: Thank you, I think this just might do the trick.

However, I would still like to know why my 3D vector trick didn't work. I can imagine why, since I am aware how multidimensional arrays are represented linearly, but it would be nice to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Linux, check the code with valgrind. If there's a memory error in your code (which sounds like what you're encountering), valgrind should expose it.